# How do I use CSS in Django?

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I am creating my application using Django, and am wondering how I can make Django use my CSS file? What settings do I need to do to make Django see the css file?

NB: On a local machine

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you're using the development server follow the [django project's how-to guide for managing static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) to setup your URL's, then reference you media files in the template -- say, an image inside an image folder from `/site_media/images/foo.gif`.

Comment: Just a quick note on those Django docs - make sure you select the documents for the version of Django you're using. Things appear to have changed a lot between versions with regard to static files.

Comment: @Sam has a great point. i couldnt figure out static files for the life of me. then, change django version installed, and voila. that was literally all i had to do because apparently i was looking at docs for the wrong version.

Answer (score 36):

More generally stated, you're asking how to serve a static file from Django. If you are running under Apache, you should read http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/

If you are running the development server (say, on your laptop), read http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Do note the **big, fat disclaimer** regarding the Django development server:

- Using this server is inefficient and insecure.
- Do not use this in a production setting.
- Use this only for development.

Comment: "Do not use this in a production setting." Do you mind expanding on this?

Comment: @Chris: You're right, the statement was a bit ambiguous. I was referring to the the Django development server. Although I have run it a few times on our production site, it was only for short periods of time while debugging gnarly problems.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I was looking at my django deployments running on apache wondering what I did wrong.  :)

Comment: Nice. I like the 3 items saying the same thing in different ways. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: I absolutely love people who come along 4.5 years after an answer was posted and down-vote it. I wonder if they even knew what Django *was* in 11/08 ... probably not. It's not the rep points that get to me, it's the displayed combination of ignorance and arrogance with just a hint of being *waaay* late to the party. I wonder how they would rate my posts to comp.lang.c in, oh let's say, 1987? Better not to ask.

Answer (score 13):

This caused me problems too for a while (404 not found errors). The missing bit for me was to edit the `STATICFILES_DIRS` tuple in settings.py to give me this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'media').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

This then picked up my CSS files in a folder called 'media' that was at the top level of my django project.

I also had:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/media/'
```

(make sure you have the leading `/` above in `STATIC_URL`)

Of course, as said above, you need to have the CSS file properly included from your html files. I had:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/ea_base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Finally, a clear, simple and elegant solution. Works fine with django 1.5.

Comment: # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
`.replace('\\','/')` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 11):

> What settings do i need to do to make Django see the css file?

None.

Make sure your template includes the CSS file (as standard HTML does) and put the CSS file on the media server.

To clarify: With Django it is highly recommended that you serve all your media (everything that isn't dynamic html) from a different server instance. How you implement that is completely up to you but most people create a subdomain.

Comment: Hi, Oli.  I know this post is close to 3 years old, but is this still the best way to link css to django templates?  This seems like it would be the easiest just linking css to an abs URL like static.example.com and just store all static files at that url.

Answer (score 8):

The official django docs didn't help me. Hope the blog post "[Django: How to serve static files](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2009/08/django-how-to-serve-media-files-css.html)" helps some of you.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way to use css with django, is to add it to your templates as static-files.

But it's a bit like ajax, I didn't find anything that tells how to include it in a standard way.

There is a [css-compressor](http://github.com/dziegler/django-css) module for django if you want to optimise its size.