# css javascript image in django

Tags: css, django

Maybe this question has been asked a lot,
but I still can't understand how to load CSS files when using django...
Please can anyone explain to me step by step how to load it?
Can I load the CSS file without the static folder or link, so I don't need to change the urls.conf but just setting in "setting.py" file?

(Sorry if my English is bad") :(

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261223/how-do-i-use-css-in-django

Comment: ya... but i still can't understand... (the static part)

Comment: I'm not sure whether I've understood your question. You're having trouble setting up the media folder?

Comment: I don't know Django, but I think the OP is asking for a step-by-step guide on including a CSS file into his website.

Comment: yah... mybe it's becaus of my english...
sorry...

i just want to load css, without using "staticfiles"

Comment: Personally, I run django and PHP on one server, and host all static media on a different server - so just use full URLs to images, JS and CSS in HTML in the templates and ignore the Django media settings. I've never used staticfiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on local machine: you have to add:

```
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/path/to/media'}),
```

on a server you don't (and more you shouldn't for security reasons) need the previous line.

So finally: here is my architecture:

```
project/
   app1/
     __init.py__
     views.py
   public/
     site_media/
        js/
           example.js
        css/
           example.css
```

in my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/thecompletepath/public/site_media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
```

and in my templates, i use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/example.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Use `RequestContext` with your views and use `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` in place of `/site_media/`, and you're golden.  You should also mention that by "on a server you don't ... need the previous line", you meant that one should use server-specific configuration to serve the media through the server rather than through django.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a normal link tag to your template.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/path/to.file.css">
```

Unless you have a dynamic CSS file, you would not want to have it related to anything in urls.py. Likewise, if you're not using the media (static) folder, you don't need to change anything in settings.py. Just insert it into your HTML in the template.

If you don't want to use an external CSS file, of course, you can always just put `<style>` tags into your templates.