# How to add CSS to my Django project website?

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

How can I add css to my django site?

Map structure:

- portfolio-project

  - portfolio

    - static

      - css

        - style.css
  - templates

Now I have this in my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link href="{% static './css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
    <p>portfolio</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you having issues importing the CSS? Or are you asking how to apply styles to the HTML? Please be explicit. Also, if you are having issues with static import please show us your static settings in your settings.py file

Comment: if i open it in my browser there is no styling added i only see portfolio as text

Comment: Do you expect it to be styling the `<title>`? If so, please read up how to apply CSS to HTML. It should have an `id` or `class` applied as such `<title class="title-red">Portfolio</title>`

Comment: this is my CSS: body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use CSS in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261223/how-do-i-use-css-in-django)

Comment: noo?? this is not what i need

Answer (score 1):

I think we're missing some info here, but you should use a relative path so it is looking in a directory relative to your project:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

This will look for the stylesheet called 'main.css' in a folder using variables from your `settings.py` file.

Your `STATIC_ROOT` is where your static files will end up after running `python manage.py collectstatic`, `STATICFILES_DIRS` is the folder that `collectstatic` is going to get your static files from. `STATIC_URL` is the URL prefix that your static files will come from.

So if you have in `settings.py`:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Your directory should look like this: `/your_project_folder/static/css/main.css`

And the template tag above will find your `main.css` file.

Comment: If you have that exact code I have to imagine it's your folder structure.
Say you have your Django project in a folder called ``django``. You should have your settings inside ``django/project/settings.py``. Your css file should then be in ``django/static/css/style.css``. Does your structure look like that?

Comment: Make sure the name of your CSS file matches across the board, in your site structure you are calling it ``main.css`` and in your sample HTML you have ``style.css``.

Comment: What about your folder structure? What does that look like exactly?

Comment: i changed it exactly take a look.

Comment: Put the ``static`` folder on the same level as ``templates``.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in development, do thi's on your settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Finally, in your html, this:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you are in production, change STATICFILES_DIRS to STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: Can you send the repository on github?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the code below:

```
<link href="{% static './css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

With the code below

```
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```